# Phonegap/ios7 - deviceready event not triggered on reload

Tags: cordova, ios7

Our Phonegap hybrid app works fine when it is loaded first. In this scenario, it is clear the deviceready event fired correctly and the application got started.  No issues.

We have a requirement to reload the application at some point.  We simply do a location.reload() on the index.html (the main application html file).  Here is where the issue starts in ios 7 devices. The application doesn't get started and it appears that deviceready is not fired.

My questions are:

```
1) In ios 7 devices, is the deviceready fired only once?
2) If it is so, how can we catch it when we reload the application?
```

We don't have this issue in android devices.

Comment: Vijey, does it work after a reload in iOS 6?  I found this, which is for a specific version of Cordova.  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5037

Comment: Jason, It works fine in IOS 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your Phonegap version? We also had this issue with 3.0, **we upgraded to 3.3** and it seems to be fixed with that!

Answer (score 0):

I spent weeks recently on a very similar issue (I was using PhoneGap Build if it matters).  For me if the ios app was resumed after not being used for a while (days or hours) but being open in the background, it would reload the page and everything but not fire the deviceready event.  It turns out that for me, 3.6.3 was the problem and pushing back to 3.3 worked.  I'm not sure about 3.4 or 3.5.

I'm not sure if my issue is the same as yours but they seem quite similar.  I too was only having the problem in iOS and not on Android.