# Cleaver page reload triggers a "deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds"

Tags: ios, cordova, uiwebview

In an iOS app I'm using Phonegap / Cordova Cleaver to host a web view.  For various reasons I didn't want to use the InAppBrowser or external browser, so I added my own navigation buttons with a UIWebViewDelegate.

On the first load of any page, things work great, but returning to the page through a back navigation button or window.location.reload, the deviceready event will not fire.

This error has been asked about many times on here, but it seems there are many ways to trigger it. I have tried [upgrading Cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21783505/519030) (to 3.3.0 from 2.8.0).  I made sure my config.xml file [plugins match](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18304132/519030) what I'm actually compiling with.  I've stripped the html and javascript down to just the Cordova docs example.

My view controller's code looks a bit like this:

```
@interface MyViewController () <UIWebViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation MyViewController 

UIButton *backButton;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];

     self.webView.delegate = self;

     // … style and place the button, frame, etc.
}

- (void)backButtonPressed
{
     NSLog(@"backButtonPressed");
     if (self.webView.canGoBack) [self.webView goBack];

     // this loads the page but the deviceready event will not subsequently fire!!
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
     NSLog(@"webViewDidStartLoad");

     // do some stuff
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
     NSURLRequest *currentRequest = [webView request];
     NSLog(@"Current URL is %@", [currentRequest URL]);

     // do some stuff
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
     NSLog(@"webView:didFailLoadWithError");
     // do some stuff
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reading the other related answers on here, I suspect my situation was a bit unique, but I spent an embarrassing amount of time hitting my head against the keyboard on this one, following many a red herring, and so I thought to post my experience.

The issue is that a Cleaver web view is inheriting from CDVViewController.  Cordova does it's own work on page interception, and I forgot to call super in webViewDidStartLoad, webViewDidFinishLoad, and webView: didFailLoadWithError.

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
     [super webViewDidStartLoad:webView];

     NSLog(@"webViewDidStartLoad");

     // now the back button and page reload will work, and deviceready will fire
}
```